# Windows Phone Licensing Module code is proper or not?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I have written the code to purchase free trial app using In App Purchase (WP8) and using MarketPlace (For WPF and WP8). I just want to be assure that my code is perfect or not before submitting to Marketplace for final.

This method I use it to validate the license. iSettings.IsAppPurchased is the property used to save or get the value from IsolatedStorageSettings. If propuct is purchase it will return true else false.

```
    internal static void CheckLicense()
    {
        if (iSettings.IsAppPurchased)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Check license of Marketplace
        LicenseInformation licInfo = new LicenseInformation();

        //It always return false from device and emulator. 
        if (!licInfo.IsTrial())
        {
            iSettings.IsAppPurchased = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            iSettings.IsAppPurchased = false;
        }


        MyStore.InitializeStore();
        // Return true if target device is WP8 else False
        if (MyStore.IsStoreEnabled)
        {
            //Overload Method
            CheckLicense(MyStore.Store);
        }
    }
```

This is overloaded method to check license if app purchased using In App Purchase.

```
    internal static void CheckLicense(StoreBase store)
    {
        var productLicenses = store.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;

        if (productLicenses != null && productLicenses.Count > 0)
        {
            ProductLicenseBase lic = productLicenses["In_App_Product_ID"];
            if (lic.IsActive)
            {
                iSettings.IsAppPurchased = true;
                store.ReportProductFulfillment(lic.ProductId);
            }
            else
            {
                iSettings.IsAppPurchased = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the last one is for purchasing app using In App Purchase feature.

```
    internal static void PurchaseIfTrial()
    {
        MyStore.InitializeStore();

        if (!MyStore.IsStoreEnabled)
        {
            MarketplaceDetailTask task = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
            task.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
            task.ContentIdentifier = null;
            task.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckLicense();

            if (!iSettings.IsAppPurchased)
            {
                MyStore.Store.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("In_App_Product_ID", false);
                CheckLicense(MyStore.Store);
            }
        }
    }
```

I call method CheckLicense on Launching app event.

I have tested this code on device and emulator, but IsTrial() method always return false. Is it because of beta version.

I got In App Purchase code from this link.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-45--Adding-In-App-Purchase-as-a-light-up-feature-to-your-Windows-Phone-7-Games

Please suggest me if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to say if your code is "perfect" or not. You will be able to tell if it is by testing it.

The "IsTrial" function will only behave correctly once the app is installed from the marketplace.
For advice on testing this functionality see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967557%28v=VS.92%29.aspx